# IAP Windows Phone 8.1 Error: HRESULT: 0x805A0194

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, in-app-purchase

I have an error with the IAP, where I try to load the product list.

```
            var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationByProductIdsAsync(
                                new string[] { "Guld_pose_1" });
```

I get the error `HRESULT: 0x805A0194` which I have read around should be misalignment between comitted version PhoneProductId and Publisher ID, according to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6357af61-3809-4b62-9c98-c578e37e00c4/exception-0x805a0194-calling-currentapploadlistinginfoasync?forum=wpdevelop) and [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementing-in-app-purchase-on-windows-phone-8--cms-22593).

How do I find these numbers on the new dev store, I can only find the guides to the old? 
I have found two publisher IDs on the dev center but no phoneproductID, or is this the SID?

A bit confused hope for some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And as always when you start the bounty the solution appears.

The issue is that I am developing a Wp8.1 silverlight app. When looking on the dev page you will not see the productId immediately shown. I found from a link that for wp8.1 the productId is part of the url for the app.

Go to the app on the devcenter. Choose the app -> app management -> app identity.

At the bottom of the page you can find the different [links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt148561.aspx): http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Copy the part after `=` and insert it on `package.appxmanifest` and `WMAppManifest.xml` as the ProductId, and the error dissapears.